# how to write a complete text using calligraphic fonts?

Tags: fonts, text

I like to write a complete text using a calligraphic font. Any hints?
Ulises

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE. In this link https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html there are many calligraphic fonts (with o without math support). Is it this similar to the request? For example I have used `Calligra Fonts`: https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligra/ Here I have added a snapshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\normalfont}{\calligra}
\AtBeginDocument{\normalfont}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots and lots of system fonts that have a calligraphic quality. To you wish to use a system font -- as opposed to a font provided by TeX distribution -- you will need to load the `fontspec` package which, in turn, requires the document to be compiled with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

If you happen to be on a MacOS system, you may want to give [Zapfino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapfino) a try. (It's a commercial font, but it comes preinstalled on MacOS systems -- and maybe other systems too, but I don't know that for a fact.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} % optional

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Zapfino}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\normalfont}{\calligra}

\begin{document}
\begin{calligra}
\section*{\centering \Huge This is the Calligraphy front} 
\end{calligra}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!